# DataGridView ComboBox index is wrong

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem adding text to a combobox in the datagrid. 
I have the problem commented on saying this is wrong here. If someone could show me the correct way to do it thanks.

note: all other info is correct.

Here is the code.

```
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
            foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
            {
                if (movie != null)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)movieListDataViewBox.Rows[0].Clone();
                    row.Cells[0].Value = movie["Name"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = movie["Rating"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = movie["Disk"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = movie["LengthHr"].InnerText + " Hr. " + movie["LengthMin"].InnerText + " Min.";
                    // clear the combobox here ?
                    foreach(XmlNode type in movie["Type"])
                    {
                        row.Cells[4].Value = type.InnerText; // This is wrong here
                    }
                    row.Cells[5].Value = movie["SeriesType"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[6].Value = movie["Location"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[7].Value = movie["Owner"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[8].Value = movie["Date"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[9].Value = movie["Time"].InnerText;
                    movieListDataViewBox.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
```

Edit: Here is how the xml file looks.

```
<Movie>
    <Name>Death Race</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Blu-Ray</Disk>
    <Owner>N/A</Owner>
    <Location>Basement</Location>
    <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
    <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
    <LengthMin>51</LengthMin>
    <Time>9 : 44 : 23 PM</Time>
    <Date>10/16/2013</Date>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Death Race 2</Name>
    <Type>Action</Type>
    <Type>Adventure</Type>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Disk>Combo</Disk>
    <Owner>N/A</Owner>
    <Location>Basement</Location>
    <SeriesType>Movie Series</SeriesType>
    <LengthHr>1</LengthHr>
    <LengthMin>41</LengthMin>
    <Time>9 : 52 : 34 PM</Time>
    <Date>10/16/2013</Date>
  </Movie>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the values of type into a comboboxcell? Is the Forth column a comboboxcolumn? I can't really tell from the code. I see that the code is flawed but I can't help you without this info.

Comment: yes. yes. sorry i should've explained that the fourth was the combobox cell. How is it flawed ?

Comment: You are overwriting the cell value every "for each type". I'll post a fix tomorrow if noone else does it.

Comment: ok if you can post it asap that would be great. Thanks a lot. I knew i was overwriting it. I couldn't find the right way to do it though. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: thanks i solved this though. my solved portion is above.

Comment: @deathismyfriend If you've found a solution to your problem post it as *answer* rather than as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i used that worked.

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(movieListXML);
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/MovieData");
            foreach (XmlNode movie in node.SelectNodes("Movie"))
            {
                if (movie != null)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)movieListDataViewBox.Rows[0].Clone();
                    row.Cells[0].Value = movie["Name"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = movie["Rating"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = movie["Disk"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = movie["LengthHr"].InnerText + " Hr. " + movie["LengthMin"].InnerText + " Min.";
                    var cb = row.Cells[4] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell; // this is for a combo box item in datagrid
                    cb.Items.Clear(); // this is for a combo box item in datagrid
                    XmlNodeList nodeList = movie.ChildNodes;
                    string str = "";
                    foreach(XmlNode nl in nodeList)
                    {
                        if ((nl.Name == "Type"))
                        {
                            cb.Items.Add(nl.InnerText); // this is for a combo box 
                        }
                    }
                    row.Cells[4].Value = str;

                    row.Cells[5].Value = movie["SeriesType"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[6].Value = movie["Location"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[7].Value = movie["Owner"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[8].Value = movie["Date"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[9].Value = movie["Time"].InnerText;
                    row.Cells[10].Value = "Pictures";
                    movieListDataViewBox.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
```